# SoapUI/Groovy: can not get response when set test step name variable

Tags: groovy, soapui

My groovy code is as below. I can get request and response when I use the real test step name in the:

```
def request=context.expand('${"testStepName"#request}')
def response=context.expand('${"testStepName"#response}')
```

When I change to use variable:

```
def request=context.expand('${${currentStep.name}#request}')
def response=context.expand('${${currentStep.name}#response}')**
```

I can only get request, while fail to get response. The error is

```
org.apacge.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: unexpected end of file after null
error at line: xx
```

The test step that currentStep points to has been executed and has request/reponse.

### Can anyboby here kindly help me?

```
    import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
    import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext
    import groovy.sql.Sql
    import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes
    import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep

    def currentStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepAt(6)
    log.info "currentStep.name: " + currentStep.name
    // get the hold of request
    def request=context.expand('${${currentStep.name}#request}')
    log.info " request: " + request

    // get the desired node value from request
    def xmlreq=new XmlHolder(request)

    // get the hold of response
    def response=context.expand('${${currentStep.name}#response}')
    log.info " response: " + response

    // get the desired node value from response
    def xmlres=new XmlHolder(response)
```

Comment: S.Spieker, thanks so much for your help!  It is my first question in the site. The original code format is not so good.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue efter reading the message.

http://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/Resolved-Pass-a-variable-into-context-expand-code/td-p/43025

```
    String propertySpec = '${' + currentStep.name + '#Response}'
    log.info "propertySpec : ${propertySpec}"
    def response = context.expand(propertySpec)
    log.info("context.expand(propertySpec) : ${response}")
    def xmlres=new XmlHolder(response)
```